# Racket: Using recursion to make a mergesort function

Tags: racket, mergesort

I have a Racket homework problem that asks me to create a `mergesort` function using recursion. It is supposed to take a list, split it up into smaller lists, and then sort them from least to greatest. The function is also supposed to return that sorted list without using any sorting commands in this assignment.

This is the code I have so far:

```
(define (mergesort lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) '()]
    [(= (length lst) 1) lst]
    [(let* ([index 0][end_index (- (length lst) 1)])
       (if (< (list-ref lst index) (list-ref lst (add1 index)))
           (cons...)
           (cons...) 
           ))]
    )
  )

(mergesort '(3 1 2 7 9)) ;should return (1 2 3 7 9)
```

I am struggling with figuring out how to move the elements into their proper position (from least to greatest) when the if statement is met. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Welcom @spaceman777. You have to show what you have tried and what you have tried and what is the problem that you are facing.

Comment: Start with a function for merging two sorted lists into one also sorted list.

Comment: (without using `list-ref`; that function is a red flag that you're on the wrong track)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your first comment. I am supposed to sort the elements manually without using `sort` or `mergesort`.

Comment: Think about the cases where you're merging a single element list with an empty list, or two single element lists, to get a sorted list. And then merge two of those, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

To split a list into two sublists, you can use functions `take` and `drop`. For example:

```lisp
> (define L '(5 9 1 3 7 0 8 4 6 2))

> (take L 5) ; get the first 5 elements in L
'(5 9 1 3 7)

> (drop L 5) ; skip the first 5 elements in L and get the rest
'(0 8 4 6 2)
>
```

Given two *sorted* lists, the following function returns a *sorted* list containing all elements from both lists:

```lisp
(define (merge A B)
    (cond [(empty? A) B]
          [(empty? B) A]
          [(<= (first A) (first B)) (cons (first A) (merge (rest A) B))]
          [else                     (cons (first B) (merge A (rest B)))]))
```

For example:

```
> (merge '(0 1 3 6 7) '(2 4 5 8 9))
'(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

Thus, the merge-sort algorithm can be coded as follows:

```lisp
(define (merge-sort L)
  (let ((k (quotient (length L) 2)))
    (cond [(zero? k) L]
          [else (merge (merge-sort (take L k))
                       (merge-sort (drop L k)))])))
```

Example:

```lisp
> (merge-sort '(5 9 1 3 7 0 8 4 6 2))
'(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
>
```